# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNotes' in type cast

Tags: flutter, snapshot, dart-null-safety, flutter-futurebuilder, statefulwidget

The problem lies in the FutureBuilder widget section. I am trying to get the data from a snapshot in a FutureBuilder, but I get an error as 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNotes' in type cast'. I tried declaring the _note field as late final but it still throws the same error. I have taken care of the null safety part by adding the ? in after the data type (here, it is DatabaseNotes). I still don't get what is wrong here.

**The following is the code for the NewNoteView widget:**

```
class NewNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewNoteView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewNoteView> createState() => _NewNoteViewState();
}

class _NewNoteViewState extends State<NewNoteView> {
  DatabaseNotes? _note;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }
    final text = _textController.text;
    await _notesService.updateNote(
      note: note,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> createNewNote() async {
    final existingNote = _note;
    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }
    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final email = currentUser.email!;
    final owner = await _notesService.getUser(email: email);
    return await _notesService.createNote(owner: owner);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;
    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(id: note.id);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;
    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        note: note,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New note'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: createNewNote(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                _note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNotes;
                _setupTextControllerListener();
                return TextField(
                  controller: _textController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Start typing your note...',
                  ),
                );
              default:
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

**The following is the code for NotesService:**

```
class DatabaseAlreadyOpenException implements Exception {}

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;
  List<DatabaseNotes> _notes = [];

  static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
  NotesService._sharedInstance();
  factory NotesService() => _shared;

  final _notesStreamController =
      StreamController<List<DatabaseNotes>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<DatabaseNotes>> get allNotes => _notesStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      final createdUser = createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNotes note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    // make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);

    // update DB
    final updatesCount = await db.update(notesTable, {
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 0,
    });

    if (updatesCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNotes>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(
      notesTable,
    );
    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNotes.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> getNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(
      notesTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNote();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNotes.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notes.add(note);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final numberOfDeletions = await db.delete(notesTable);
    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    return numberOfDeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      notesTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure the owner exists in the database with the correct id
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    }

    const text = '';
    // create the note
    final noteId = await db.insert(notesTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 1,
    });

    final note = DatabaseNotes(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExists();
    }

    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
    });

    return DatabaseUser(
      id: userId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    try {
      await open();
    } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
      //empty block
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException;
    }
    try {
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;
      // create the user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);
      // create the notes table
      await db.execute(createNotesTable);
      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentsDirectory;
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;
  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });
  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person id = $id, email = $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNotes {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;
  DatabaseNotes({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });
  DatabaseNotes.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud = (map[isSyncedWithCloudColumn]) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, text = $text';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNotes other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `NotesService()`

Comment: I have included the NotesService() code.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the '?' after DatabaseNotes (or DatabaseNote if you are following the FreeCodeCamp tutorial more precisely). Your IDE will probably then tell you the cast to DatabaseNotes is unnecessary. I then removed the 'as DatabaseNotes' entirely and it worked. Final line of code as below.

```
_note = snapshot.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FutureBuilder<DatabaseNotes>(your code);
```

Comment: It still throws the same error.

Comment: really _note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNotes?; this solved the issue..
i dont understand

Comment: Yeah apparently it did, I didn't think it would but the error was related to a null value so I kinda thought about the ? thingy and it worked. No more red screen on my emulator.
But I am open to your suggestion if you had another solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake and turns out I wasn't handling the null safety after all; I feel like an idiot.
I created an instance of **'DatabaseNotes?' _note**, but when I assigned the snapshot's data inside the FutureBuilder in the line **_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNotes**, I forgot to add the **?** after DatabaseNotes.
The statement should be: **_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNotes?;**

Thank you everyone for your answers and suggestions. I highly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

After

> `_note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNotes;`

just put

> *?*

This null safety sign. And your code will run errorless. My code so suffers for this **damn** sign.

Comment: You are not contributing any new insight to the existing answers. Please [edit] or delete.